# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'length') at GoogleMapReact

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am developing an app using the GoogleMapReact component and keep receiving an error stating that the length property is undefined. Is there something that I cant see? All feedback is greatly appreciated. These are the error codes I am receiving:

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'length')

react-dom.development.js:20085 The above error occurred in the  component:

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'length')
at Map (Map.jsx:19:1)

```
import React from 'react';
import GoogleMapReact from 'google-map-react';
import { Paper, Typography, useMediaQuery } from '@material-ui/core';
import LocationOnOutlinedIcon from '@material-ui/icons/LocationOnOutlined';
import Rating from '@material-ui/lab/Rating';

import useStyles from './styles';

import mapStyles from './mapStyles'


const Map = (coords, setCoords, setBounds, places, setChildClicked, weatherData) => {
    const classes = useStyles();
    const matches = useMediaQuery('(min-width:600px)');


    return (
        <div className={classes.mapContainer}>
            <GoogleMapReact
                bootstrapURLKeys={{ key: process.env.REACT_APP_GOOGLE_MAPS_API_KEY }}
                defaultCenter={coords}
                center={coords}
                defaultZoom={14}
                margin={[50, 50, 50, 50,]}
                options={{ disableDefaultUI: true, zoomControl: true, styles: mapStyles }}
                onChange={(e) => {
                    setCoords({ lat: e.center.lat, lng: e.center.lng });
                    setBounds({ ne: e.marginBounds.ne, sw: e.marginBounds.sw });
                }}

                onChildClick={(child) => setChildClicked(child)}

            >
                {places.length && places.map((place, i) => (
                    <div
                        className={classes.markerContainer}
                        lat={Number(place.latitude)}
                        lng={Number(place.longitude)}
                        key={i}
                    >

                        {!matches ?
                            <LocationOnOutlinedIcon color="primary" fontSize="large" />
                            : (
                                <Paper elevation={3} className={classes.paper}>
                                    <Typography className={classes.typography} variant="subtitle2" gutterBottom> {place.name}</Typography>
                                    <img
                                        className={classes.pointer}
                                        src={place.photo ? place.photo.images.large.url : 'https://www.rlare.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/12/Inside-1-1.jpg'}
                                        alt={place.name}
                                    />
                                    <Rating size="small" value={Number(place.rating)} name="read-only" />

                                </Paper>
                            )}

                    </div>
                ))}

                {weatherData?.list?.length && weatherData.list.map((data, i) => (
                    <div key={i} lat={data.coord.lat} lng={data.coord.lon}>
                        <img src={`https://openweathermap.org/img/w/${data.weather[0].icon}.png`} height="70px" alt="map"/>

                    </div>
                ))}

            </GoogleMapReact>
        </div>
    );
}

export default Map;
```

In the app.js file I am using the map component as follows:

```
<Grid item xs={12} md={8} style={{display: 'flex', justfiyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' }}>
             <Map 
             setChildClicked={setChildClicked}
             setCoordinates={setCoords}
             setBounds={setBounds}
             coordinates={coords}
             place={filteredPlaces.length ? filteredPlaces : places}
             weatherData={weatherData}
             />
             
         </Grid>
```

Comment: It's not saying that the `length` property is undefined, it's saying you're trying to access the `length` property of a value that is undefined. In your code sample, that's likely at `places.length`. Check that `places` is not undefined.

Comment: Props of React component should be destructured like this `const Map = ({coords, setCoords, setBounds, places, setChildClicked, weatherData}) => {` (note the curly brances) or condense into a `props` variable `const Map = (props) => {`

Comment: @BaoHuynhLam Thank you for catching  the curly braces error! I never noticed that. However, after adding them I am still receiving the same 3 error codes

Comment: Can you post code of how you are using this `Map` component and how are you passing props to it ?

Comment: Your props is called "places" but you are passing "place" to it? Not sure if this is actual error or just an SO typo ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work if you are sending the props correctly.

Put your props in curly brackets `({coords, setCoords, setBounds, places, setChildClicked, weatherData})` and check the length and data in this way `places?.length`  `places?.map` `weatherData?.list?.map`

Comment: Hi! Thank you for the feedback. One question though. When you say to check the length, are you saying to write a new line of code(Places?.length)?

Comment: No I mean add question mark before .length ´@PabloHernandez

Comment: Holy cow I did that and some of my app started to render. Thank you. But my map is still not showing

Comment: You have again filteredPlaces.length without question mark in your component of Map. You should add ? and be sure that you are passing that data to component

Comment: to clarify, it should be: {filteredPlaces?.length ? filteredPlaces: places}

Answer (score 0):

if you have react 18 there is an issue with GoogleMapReact component

https://github.com/google-map-react/google-map-react/issues/1110

for the moment the correct solution is to downgrade to version 17 ..
hope it helps...